# How do you evaluate a framework, library, or tool before adding it to your project?

Tags: frameworks

There's so many cool ideas out there ([ninject](http://ninject.org/), [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), [specflow](http://specflow.org/), etc) that look like they would help but I don't want to add something, tell others about it, and try using it just for it to be added to the growing heap of ideas that didn't quite work out. How can I determine if the promised benefits will happen and that it won't end up as something to be ignored or worked around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Have a problem
2. Identify the cost of having the problem, or the value to solving it
3. Prioritize it against other problems
4. When it's the top priority, look for a solution that solves the problem with a proportional cost

Do you have the problem that ninject solves? Is it an important problem to solve? Is it the most important? What value will you get from solving it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can tell whether any framework will deliver your expectations until you try it, and try it in anger and in context. This is usually time consuming and inevitably you'll have a few misses before you get any hits. Don't commit yourself by working through a simple sample from the authors website or howto files; these will always work and may impress but until you try to use the framework in the context of your billion user, multi-lingual, real-time on- and off- line application you're not going to find it's shortcomings.